# Java: Run multiple shell commands?

Tags: java, android, shell, adb, command-prompt

OK. I've been looking everywhere on how to execute multiple commands on a single command prompt from java. What i need to do is this, but not in command line, in code.

Execute:

```
cd C:/Android/SDK/platform-tools
adb install superuser.apk
```

..Basically i want to run adb commands from a program!!! Here is my java code so far:

MainProgram.java

```
public class MainProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      CMD shell = new CMD();
      shell.execute("cmd /K cd C:/Android/SDK/platform-tools"); //command 1
      shell.execute("cmd /C adb install vending.apk"); // command 2
   }
}
```

CMD.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class CMD {
CMD() {
}
// THIS METHOD IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
void execute(String command) {
    try
    {           
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command

    String s = null;        
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
  }     
catch(Exception e){  
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

So what happens is...i can run the first command, but that cmd terminates and when i execute the 2nd command, a new cmd is created, hence i get an error because im not in the right directory. I tried a single string command "cmd /C cd C:/blablabla /C adb remount", but that just froze up...

Essentially, command 1 is executed and terminated, then command 2 is executed and terminated. I want it to be like this: command 1 executed, command 2 executed, terminated.

**Basically i'm asking how can i run both of these commands in a row on a single command prompt???**

My final target is to have a JFrame with a bunch of buttons which execute different adb commands when clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to make a batch file then call that from program
of course you could just say

```
C:/Android/SDK/platform-tools/adb install superuser.apk
```

there's no need to cd to a file if you name it directly

although what you are looking for is already made in ddms.bat which provides a complete visual link to adb

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about "C:/Android/SDK/platform-tools/adb install superuser.apk" ...that pretty much solves the problem. well done!

Answer (score 0):

Create file as `something.bat` and set the contents to:

```
cd C:/Android/SDK/platform-tools
adb install superuser.apk
```

Then call:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("something.bat");
```

all commands in the bat file are executed.